# WordPress Answers Chat

Tags: discussion, chat

We now have an official home for WPA chat in the new merged SE chat site:

http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6/stop-press

Answer (score 1):

Hi **@Thomas McDonald**

This could be interesting if there were some standard times we scheduled for an hour long chat once a week. Right now we just don't have enough people here to make a chat room work organically.

-Mike