# WPA Meta Meeting #1

Tags: discussion

Me and Jan were talking on chat this evening, and in conjunction with Mike's response [here](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/wordpress-answers-chat/230#230) we decided our use of chat would possibly be much more productive if we were to have an assigned time when we would join and discuss issues etc.

It's a bit difficult to decide upon a time when you don't know others schedules, so our first planned meeting is:

### Saturday 6th November, 2100 UTC

which will cover Europe (evening) and the USA as it will be mid-afternoon (correct me if I'm wrong)

#### Topics to discuss

So far me and Jan both have a couple of items regarding tagging we would like to discuss, and we both agreed promotion was the most important issue facing the site at the moment. Therefore, I'd like to propose a rough agenda:

- Promotion
- Unanswered meta questions
- Tagging and organisation
- Other issues

If you could register yourself as attending it would be appreciated, just so we know roughly how many people will be attending. If you can't attend everything will be available in the room transcript, and you could always bring up any issues you see on Meta afterwards.

You can register yourself as attending [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/6/stop-press?tab=schedule)

Comment: Of course, if you have something to add to the agenda, please say so. Maybe as an answer, so we can fine-tune each point in a separate discussion.

Comment: 4pm EST right?

Comment: [5PM EDT](http://everytimezone.com/). Daylight Saving Time ends on 11/7, so we're 4 hours behind UTC. (I don't mind timezones, but I *hate* daylight saving time.)

Comment: The biggest downside of a Saturday afternoon meeting ... is that it's the same time that my team's playing football.  Gotta have your priorities, right? :-)  But I'll try to be there anyway (though I apologize in advance if I'm insanely distracted at the time).

Answer (score 1):

Just an answer to bump this to the top. Today, 21:00 UTC. It is [scheduled in the chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/6/stoppress?tab=schedule) so you can see the correct time.