# Vote! The Great Chat Room Rename Project

Tags: discussion, chat

It's been quite a while since our chat room started ( [WordPress Answers Chat](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/wordpress-answers-chat) ) and it seems it was named near randomly

> Because it's what Mark called it when he imported it I believe
>
> [*Thomas McDonald*](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/119821#119821)

I feel ***StopPress*** never quite had connection with community. Also **Press* is overused and lame.

Let's rename it!

## Answer with: name idea

- **one per answer**
- **format as heading**
- **(down)vote those you (dis)like**

Note that tag line on other hand is quite fine (*Where humor doesn’t work.*) and, if I remember right, was produced later by community. However if you feel there is better tagline to go with your title idea - do include it.

## Optionally: add tagline to go with name

- **format as subheading**

Please format it as subheading to distinguish tag line suggestions from things you just add for explanation/context.

PS there might be reusable ideas with historical attachment in [What should our domain name be?](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/what-should-our-domain-name-be) however [lead "queryposts" choice went on to have different life](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1087/queryposts-com-lives).

Answer (score 31, accepted):

## The Loop

Because some topics are endless.

Comment: ... are you in it?

Comment: if ( have_chat() ) : while ( have_chat() ) : procrastinate();

Comment: `while(TRUE) gpl_debate();`

Answer (score 5):

## Bottom of the Trap

> WordPress is not a relationship, it's a trap [...] welcome to the bottom
>
> [*Rarst*](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/9557976#9557976)

Answer (score 4):

## sidebar

or possibly

## get_sidebar()

Answer (score 3):

## Victim Support and Therapy.

In association with the GPL and Freedom*

*please note - Freedom may not be used without permission

Comment: maybe shorten to "Victim Support and Therapy", too bulky (also maybe Wictim ? :)

Comment: @rarst Good idea, fairly sure we wouldn't be allowed to use the word "WordPress" anyway. Freedom!

Answer (score 3):

## query_people

#### The most efficient way to (mis)take working time for pastime.

Answer (score 2):

## QueryPeople

At least it's about getting people together.

Comment: I really like the idea. I would slightly change this to `query_people();` or `query_people`, though.

Comment: @tf Add that as separate answers.

Answer (score 2):

### WPSE_Query

#### Custom queries for WordPress Answers

Answer (score 0):

## in_the_loop();

This was a piggyback off @toscho
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/in_the_loop

Answer (score -1):

## Good chat room

### is waste of time and energy

(play on famous quote from Otto)

Answer (score -1):

## Metadata

.......................

Answer (score -1):

What about **ChatPress** ?

`capital_P_dangit()` still applies here.

Comment: Nope. There's a filter for that.

Answer (score -2):

## I like Baoot

[image]

Comment: http://wp-themes.com/?p=19

Answer (score -5):

## Positivum

*you know the why*

Comment: I guess I get a badge for that answer :D